# I cannot clone repository although I have access to it

Tags: git, ssh, windows-7, clone

I am trying to clone an online repository on my laptop with Windows 7 but I get error "Permission denied publickey.

The strange thing is that I have complete access to the (very safe) repository which I want to clone, and I also routinely access it and clone it on my Ubuntu machine.

Isn't having access to repository itself enough to make a clone of it?

Thx!

Comment: You are using the ssh protocol to do the clone? Is the repo hosted on [github](https://github.com/)? [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org)? Are you sure you have setup your ssh public/private key correctly and added it? Tutorials for github and bitbuckets can be found [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git) and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) respectively. Also, can you update your post with the `git clone` command you are running?

Comment: Thank you for joining, I solved it in the meanwhile with a help from friend.